# What does “fortune” mean in “seek one’s fortune”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

“Fortune” has 2 meanings (per Google):

- luck or chance, as in the wheel of fortune
- a large amount of money

So what does the expression “seek one’s fortune” mean?

Neither of the above make sense in that context, as one cannot seek for one’s own luck, and the phrase doesn’t mean “go and find wealth you’ve already got”. (Merriam-Webster has “try to become rich” - but why not just “seek a fortune” then?)

I’ve always read it as a sort of cross between the two, i.e. going after a beneficial (and remunerative!) destiny.

Is that a third meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The early meaning of “**fortune**”  was “lot”(n.) or “fate”:

OED

> **1.a. Chance, hap, or luck, regarded as a cause of events and changes in men's affairs. Often** (after Latin) **personified as a goddess, ‘the power supposed to distribute the lots of life according to her own humour’** (Johnson); **her emblem is a wheel, betokening vicissitude.**

> a1300   Cursor Mundi 32719   *Dame fortune turnes þan hir quele And castes vs dun vntil a wele.* [My translation: Dame Fortune turns then her wheel / And casts us down into a well.]
>
> a1616   W. Shakespeare Henry VI, Pt. 3 (1623) iv. iv. 19   *Though Fortune’s mallice ouerthrow my State, My mind exceeds the compass of her Wheel.*

At about the same time, it also had the meaning

> **3.a. The chance or luck (good or bad) which falls to any one as his lot in life or in a particular affair.**
>
> c1374   G. Chaucer tr. Boethius De Consol. Philos. (Cambr.) ii. metr. iii. 27   *Wol~thow thanne trusten in the tomblynge fortunes of men?* [My translation: Why then should we trust in the randomly changing fortunes of men?]

And also

> **d. That which is to befall a person in the future: chiefly in to tell a person his fortune and to tell fortunes** (said of would-be seers).
>
> 1413   Pilgr. Sowle (1483) iv. v. 60   *Alisandre..fond two trees, whiche trees told hym his fortunes.* [My translation: Alisandre..found two trees, and those trees told him his fortune.]

And, at the same time, it developed a positive meaning:

> **4.** absol. (= good fortune): **Good luck; success, prosperity.**
>
> 1390   J. Gower Confessio Amantis III. 166   *Though thou victoire have on honde, Fortune may nought stonde alwey.* [My translation: Though victory is close, Fortune will not impede you (i.e. will help you..)]

By the late 1500s, the association between “being fortunate” and being wealthy had been made:

> **6. Position as determined by wealth; amount of wealth; concrete a person's possessions collectively, wealth, ‘substance’; … ordinarily implying a somewhat ample amount. to make a, one's fortune.**
>
> 1596   E. Spenser Second Pt. Faerie Queene vi. ix. sig. Gg6v   *For wisedome is most riches; fooles therefore They are, which fortunes doe by vowes deuize.* [My translation: For wisdom is the greatest of all riches; it is fools who marry for wealth.]

And thus **To seek one’s fortune**:

> **3c. to try one's fortune: to make trial how it will turn out (with the hope of its proving favourable).** Similarly **to seek one's fortune**.
>
> 1574   J. Baret Aluearie F 955   *I will adventure, or trie and seeke my fortune.*

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seek%20one%27s%20fortune) defines "seek one's fortune" as "to try to become rich." [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/seek+(one%27s)+fortune) and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/seek-your-fortune) also define it as related to gaining wealth. So "a large amount of money" is the relevant sense of "fortune," though [as Merriam-Webster notes](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fortune) this sense of fortune can be extended to describe success or wealth more generally.

But the question is: why is it "one's" fortune, not just "a" fortune? The answer is that possessive nouns often refer to things other than literal ownership. In this case, it refers to the fortune one is allotted or destined to receive, not to a fortune one already possesses.